# jquery file input add

Tags: jquery, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I am trying to create a file upload form and have been able to do so successfully. I have also add a jquery snippet to display the name, size, mime of each of the selected files.

What I haven't been able to resolve is, 
1 - How do I retain the files selected when I decide to add more files to the form prior to uploading? So I select the files, close the dialog, I click on the file input button again and select more files. The standard behavior will over-write what has been selected. I want to retain what I selected and add more to it.

2- How do I remove some of the selected files from the selection without resetting the entire selection?

Here is my form field:

```
    <input id="files" type="file" multiple="" name="files[]" class="green btn"/>
```

Here is my jquery snippet:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#file_list').html('\
        <div class="portlet box yellow">\
            <div class="portlet-title">\
                <div class="caption">\
                    <i class="fa fa-reorder"></i>Project Attachments\
                </div>\
                <div class="tools">\
                    <a href="#" class="collapse"></a>\
                </div>\
            </div>\
            <div class="portlet-body">\
                <table id="files_table" class="table table-striped table-hover">\
                   <thead>\
                    <th>File</th>\
                    <th>File Name</th>\
                    <th>File Size</th>\
                    <th>File Creation Date</th>\
                   </thead>\
                   <tbody>\
                   </tbody>\
                 </table>\
             </div>\
        </div>\
    ');
    $('#files').on('change', function(){
        var fileList = this.files;
        var numFiles = this.length;


        for (var i = 0, numFiles = fileList.length; i < numFiles; i++) {
            var file = fileList[i];
            $('#file_list #files_table tbody').append('\
            <tr>\
                <td></td>\
                <td>'+file.name+'</td>\
                <td>'+file.size+'</td>\
                <td>'+file.type+'</td>\
            </tr>\
        ');
        }
    });
});
```

I have been playing around with this for 2 days and I have hit a dead end. Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: do you want to add more files in a single form?

Comment: u cant do it with one <input id="files" type="file" multiple="" name="files[]" class="green btn"/>, instead add 'n' number of input file field for 'n' number of files, then u will take file[0][name], file[1][name] and so on in php

Answer (score 0):

I guess thus lib will solve your problem easily.

```
https://plugins.jquery.com/blueimp-file-upload-jquery-ui/
```

Answer (score 0):

Find a way to add a .selected property to each file in your this.files object.

Add an onclick function to each of the HTML inputs that adjusts the .selected property for the specific file in this.files based on the HTML input value of .checked

Add an if statement in your for loop along the lines of

```
if ( file.selected )
{
    continue;
    // or something
}
```